# Why is my SOAP call not working with PHP?

Tags: php, soap, soapui

I am trying to call a SOAP function. I tested the function on SOAP UI and it's working fine. It gives me a successful response. However, when I try to call the function with PHP, it gives me this error:

> SoapFault exception: [Server] Internal Error in
>   /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php:24
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php(24):
>   SoapClient->__soapCall('track', Array) #1 {main}

I have tried everything, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
$username = 'XXXXXXXX';
$pro = '90986629';

        $wsdl = "https://unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/ShipmentTracking.wsdl";

        $request = array(
            'trackingNumber' => $pro,
            'userId ' => $username
        );

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

        try
        {

            $result = $client->__soapCall("track", array(
                $request
            ));

            print_r($result);

        }
        catch(SoapFault $ex)
        {
            $ex->getMessage();
            echo $ex;

        }
```

And here is a snapshot of my test with SOAP UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Track is a `complexType` so you'll need to pass it an object, not array:

```
<element name="track">
<complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element name="trackingNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="deliveryNotificationRequested" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="deliveryNotificationEmail1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="deliveryNotificationEmail2" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 </sequence>
</complexType>

$request = new StdClass();
$request->trackingNumber = '12345';
$request->userId = '222'; 

$client->track($request);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: You are sure that `request` properties contain `strings`? Also, are you sure the error is exactly the same? The error should not mention `array` as you are no longer passing one...or shouldn't be rather

Comment: I am using strings for the parameters. Here is the error I'm getting when I try that: SoapFault exception: [Server] Internal Error in /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php(21): SoapClient->__call('track', Array) #1 /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php(21): SoapClient->track(Object(stdClass)) #2 {main}

Comment: init your soap client with the `trace` option, `$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1, 'exceptions' => 0));` Then in your catch block take a look at the last response message `$client->__getLastResponse()`;

Comment: This is the response that I'm getting now:  

SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Internal Error [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php [line:protected] => 22 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php [line] => 22 [function] => __call [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => track [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [trackingNumber] => 90986629 [userId ] => XXXX ) ) ) ) [1] =>

Comment: Array ( [file] => /home/bookweeb/unus.site/V2/Dashboard/includes/npmeTracking.php [line] => 22 [function] => track [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [trackingNumber] => 90986629 [userId ] => XXXX ) ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => Internal Error [faultcode] => Server [faultcodens] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ )

Comment: Alright, now set exceptions to true or 1 in your client init and go from there. The server doesn't like something you are giving it.

Comment: Thanks! When I set the exceptions to true, I get an error again. This is what I'm getting from __getLastResponse() 

ServerInternal Error

I wonder what the server doesn't like because the request from SOAP UI seems to work without any problem.